# Memory leak in java

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jprofiler, finalize

I used jprofiler to detect memory leak for my client code.At starting the memory used by java.util.hashmap$entry was increasing drastically up to 1700KB. after that it decreased too.  The Heap dump show java.lang.ref.finalizer was using maximum of memory.  What doest it conclude? When i try to find finalize() in my source code it was not there. in HTML file finalize() was used like this.   [finalize](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html?is-external=true#finalize()),    what does it mean? The cause is finalize() or the reference hashmap$entry is causing the leak?

Comment: There is no such thing as `java.lang.ref.finalizer` or `java.util.hashmap$entry`.  Please update the question with the REAL class names or method names or whatever they are.

Comment: Why do you think there is a memory leak? Does your application give you an `OutOfMemoryException`? Perhaps you simply need to change the amount of memory you start the application with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to look for a memory leak, you should look at how much memory is used after a Full GC, twice if you have lots of finalisable references, otherwise you are likely to see lots of temporary objects which don't matter.

I suspect neither of the data types you are seeing are a problem esp if they go down in usage periodically. Look for consumption which only goes up.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Actually almost every data data types memory consuming value is increasing. I mean to say that if consumption is now 50kb after 10 min it's 56kb and just after performing gc the consumption is 53kb means after 10 min 3 kb memory increased and periodically it increased in this manner only. Does it confirm that my application has memory leak?

Comment: Many MB increase after a Full GC might be a leak.  I wouldn't worry about a few KB as it could be "noise".  If everything is increasing it points to a common factor e.g. a collection which holds all these increasing classes.

Answer (score 0):

> What does it conclude?

First, your so-called "evidence" is garbled, and it is not clear what the ungarbled version should be.  However, based on some guesswork ... I can see no clear signs of a memory leak at all.

Rather, it *looks like* what would happen if you had a large `WeakHashMap` that either became unreachable, or that got cleared out because the GC noticed that the heap was getting too full.

However, my guesswork could be wrong, and there could be a leak here ...

> The cause is finalize() or the reference hashmap$entry is causing the leak?

Not necessarily either.  (In fact, *if* there is really a storage leak at all, it is *unlikely* that either of those is the direct cause.)

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Actually almost every data data types memory consuming value is increasing. I mean to say that if consumption is now 50kb after 10 min it's 56kb and just after performing gc the consumption is 53kb means after 10 min 3 kb memory increased and periodically it increased in this manner only. Does it confirm that my application has memory leak?

Comment: A single data-point is not evidence of a memory leak.  A consistent long term trend would be evidence of a leak.